# Why does graphicsmagick enlarge the image size when rotating it, but imagemagick does not?

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

GraphicsMagick command as below:

```
    convert cute_dog.jpg -rotate 90 -quality 92 cute_dog_rotate_gm.jpg
```

ImageMagick command as below:

```
    convert cute_dog.jpg -rotate 90 -quality 92 cute_dog_rotate.jpg
```

Q: How to reduce the file generated by GraphicsMagick?

[image: size info]

[image_link](https://pixabay.com/zh/photos/corgi-dog-pet-canine-rain-animal-4415649/)

Comment: solved by use  -define jpeg:preserve-settings.